# Unexplained ParseException for SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse dates that appear in the format `"01-26-2012 03:07 AM"`.

I created this `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a");
```

Yet every time I parse the following:

```
String date = "01-26-2012 03:07 AM";
Date myDate =  DATE_FORMAT.parse(date.trim());
```

I get a `ParseException`:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01-26-2012 03:07 AM"
>       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Is my `SimpleDateFormat` string correct? Is there anything else that might be stopping it from parsing?

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely a locale issue. If you try with an English locale for example, it should work:

```
DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Since you don't specify a locale, the default one for your system is used, and the "AM" might not be parsed correctly.

The code below outputs

> myDate = Thu Jan 26 03:07:00 GMT 2012

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String date = "01-26-2012 03:07 AM";
    DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date myDate = DATE_FORMAT.parse(date.trim());
    System.out.println("myDate = " + myDate);
}
```

As a side note, if you change the code to `Locale.CHINESE` for example, you would get a parse exception.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried with Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.US, and few other locales.  Still having the same issue though :(

Comment: It works for me - I posted a full working example for reference - maybe you could try it to confirm that it does not work. What version of Java do you use?

Comment: I'm using Java 1.6.0_33.  I copied the example in your comment, it still does not work.

Comment: @user1854772 I can't reproduce your issue so it's difficult to say what goes wrong. It might seem stupid but are you running the right code? If you run my example again with `"01-26-2012 01:23 PM"` do you get a corresponding parse exception (with 01:23 PM and not 03:07 AM)? Are you importing `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`?

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! Mine still didn't work, but comparing the two strings I found a difference in whitespace (mine had an &nbsp instead of a regular space)

Comment: @user1854772 That could explain your issue indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to use `SimpleDateFormat` as a static object as it is NOT [thread safe](http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html). I can't say that is the problem here, but could be a pointer.